# Download Crystal report as PDF on Server or Central location

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence

We are using the open document to call the crystal report directly to generate a PDF output that can be viewed in the Browser but we want it store on server or any Central Location//

Let me elaborate my quest more

I have a link on which if user click from any location that link will open a report in PDF and then we can download it manually.

Now what i did is i made some setting in my machine Chrome browser so instead of opening the report in browser it will directly downloading in my machine . But this is not best solution and limited to myself only.

CAN we add something in our link by which we can directly download the report in PDF format and that too on BO server or any central disk location not on clients machine ? (Means if the user is at any location and if he hits that link the report get auto downloaded into our SAP BO Server C: derive) not on client machine.

Check the Link

http://ETLHOSAPDEV01.etlife.com:8080/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&iDocID=ARmDcaMT..NCjqK9iF0MITE&lsSGET_APPN_NBR=2&lsSGET_REQUIREMENT=abc&sOutputFormat=p

Comment: why don`t you use the http response from Crystal Report it self it will show you the Open\Download dialog box...so user can decide to open or download

Answer (score 0):

```
In JAVA using Apache POI you can save the crystal reports into server location path.

XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("give the required path"));
        printOutputController.export(ReportExportFormat.MSWord, out);
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();
```